# Why didn't Semmelweis perform a simpler experiment, to stop all the anatomical work?

Tags: 19th-century, medicine

Levy wrote in his paper criticizing [Semmelweis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ignaz_Semmelweis): "*Why wasn't a simpler and more reliable experiment performed, to stop all the anatomical work?*". That sounds like a reasonable argument to me. Did Semmelweis respond to it, and, if so, how?

Why didn't Semmelweis decide to stop all the autopsies as soon as he noticed that puerperal fever almost always happens when the student assisting birth comes directly from an autopsy? He noticed that way before the death of Jakob Kolletschka, right? So, why didn't he act on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Then how will the autopsies get done?

They weren't performing them for fun.  There were few ways to study anatomy, and autopsies on dead bodies were important, as it actually showed what anatomy was.